# What is the essence of the theorem by Von Staudt

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, bernoulli-numbers

The [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) are defined as coefficients $\beta_i$ in the expansion

$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\beta_0 + \frac{\beta_1x}{1!} + \frac{\beta_2x^2}{2!} + \frac{\beta_3x^3}{3!} + .....$

where $\beta_0=1$,$\beta_1=-\frac{1}{2}$ and for $i \ge 1$ $\beta_{2i+1}=0$.

Hardy and wright in their book first state the following  theorem by Von Staudt regarding Bernoulli numbers

> $\beta_k + \sum_{p-1|k} \frac{1}{p} = l$ , where $l$ is an integer and summation is over primes $p$ such that $p-1$ divides k.

Right after stating the theorem the authors say the following

> " In particular Von Staudt's theorem shows there that there is no  squared factor in the denominator of any Bernoullian number ".

What do the authors mean by this ? When they say "denominator of any Bernoullian number" , do they consider the Bernoulli numbers in reduced form ? What am I missing ?

Comment: If a number is given by an integer minus a sum of reciprocals of distinct primes, it is a rational number and the denominator of its reduced form is simply given by the product of the previous primes (in particular, it is square-free).

Comment: So the denominator of $B_{2m}$ is given by the product of primes $p$ such that $(p-1)\mid (2m)$.